# Can't delete file after displaying it in html object using Spring MVC

Tags: java, html, jsp, spring-mvc

Plop,

I am trying to delete a file that is not stored in my spring project.

I had mapped the ressource folder with :

```xml
<mvc:resources mapping="/rootfolder/**" location="file:C:/Users/mypc/dev/rootfolder/" />
```

When I try to delete a file which was never display everything work fine. The problem is showing when I try to delete a file which was displayed once in my web app.

Even when I try to delete it manually in the file system I get this message:

> This action can not be performed because the file is open in Java (TM)
>   Platform SE binary

home.jsp

```html
    <c:when test="${fileExtension == 'application/vnd.ms-excel'}">
        <object data="rootfolder/<sec:authentication property="principal.username" />/${fileName}"
            type="${fileExtension}" width="100%" style="height:50em">
        </object>
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${fileExtension == 'application/pdf'}">
        <object data="rootfolder/<sec:authentication property="principal.username" />/${fileName}" 
            type="${fileExtension}" width="100%" style="height:50em"> 
        </object>
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${(fileExtension == 'image/png') ||  (fileExtension == 'image/jpg')}">
        <img src="rootfolder/<sec:authentication property="principal.username" />/${fileName}" width="100%" style="height:50em"/>
    </c:when>
```

...

```html
<form name="deleteFileForm" action="<c:url value="/deleteFile"/>" method="POST">
    <button name="deleteFile" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">
        <input id="deletefilename" name="deletefilename" class="hidden" type="text" value="${filesList}"/>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </button>
</form>
```

deleteController.java:

```html
Authentication      auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
String              name = auth.getName();
User                user = service.getUsersFromLogins(name);
String              fileName = request.getParameter("deletefilename");
File                folder;

File file = new File(user.getUsr_folderpath()+"/"+fileName);

if(file.delete())
{
    redir.addFlashAttribute("deleteSucced", message.getMessage("billing.message.success.delete", 
        new String[]{file.getName()}, Locale.getDefault()));
}
else
{
    redir.addFlashAttribute("deleteFailed", message.getMessage("billing.message.error.delete", 
        new String[]{file.getName()}, Locale.getDefault()));
}
```

DownloadFileController:

```xml
Authentication      auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String              name = auth.getName();
        User                user = service.getUsersFromLogins(name);
        String              fileName = request.getParameter("dlfilename");
        InputStream         inputStream = null;
        try 
        {
            String filePathToBeServed = user.getUsr_folderpath()+"/"+request.getParameter("dlfilename");
            File fileToDownload = new File(filePathToBeServed);
            inputStream = new AutoCloseInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileToDownload));
            response.setContentType("application/force-download");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+fileName); 
            IOUtils.copy(inputStream, response.getOutputStream());
            response.flushBuffer();
            inputStream.close();
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Request could not be completed at this moment. Please try again.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally { IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream); }
```

Initialisation of fileExtension:

```html
if(user.getUsr_folderpath() != null)
            {
                folder = new File(user.getUsr_folderpath());
                folderManager.listFilesForFolder(folder);
                redir.addFlashAttribute("fileExtension", fileManager.getFileType(folderManager.getFiles().get(0)));
            }
```

folderManager:

```xml
private ArrayList<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();

public void listFilesForFolder(final File folder) 
{
    for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) 
    {
        if (fileEntry.isDirectory())
            listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
        else
            files.add(fileEntry.getName());
    }
}

public List<String> getFiles() 
{
    return files;
}
```

fileManager.getFileType:

```html
public String getFileType(String fileName)
{
    String  fileExtension = fileName.substring(fileName.length()-3);
    if (fileExtension.toLowerCase().equals("pdf"))
        return("application/pdf");
    else if (fileExtension.toLowerCase().equals("png"))
        return("image/png");
    else if(fileExtension.toLowerCase().equals("jpg"))
        return("image/jpg");
    else if (fileExtension.toLowerCase().equals("xls"))
        return("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    return null;
}
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Are you sure this is only one place where your application has access to this file?

Comment: The only place where I open an inputStream (which need to be closed) is in my downloadFileController (I added it to my post). The other functions are using File or MultipartFile which can't be closed.

Comment: May be these Controllers are executed at same time? I.e. your server recieves a request for "DeleteController" while downloading is not finished yet.

Comment: They are mapped on different form and different submit button.

Comment: yes. And it means that Controllers on server could work in different threads. So you can call code from DeleteController while Downloading is not yet done, so file is still open.

Comment: Ok I get what you mean. But in most session I don't download files. I just  try to delete a file which was displayed on my browser object once and it's not working. In this case I don't use inputstream.

Comment: Ok, I'd re-read your question and found this: "when I try to delete a file which was displayed once". 
I'm sure problem is here. File stay opened when after "displayed once".

Comment: Yes I think it's about this but I don't really get how to close a file which is open in an html object. In controller side I'm just using the File object which doesn't need to be close.

Comment: Can you show a part of your jsp where you initialize a variable "fileExtension"?
And at all where you access file

Comment: I have added my fileExtension initialization.

Comment: So, you don't open file with your app. Ok. But it means you can't close it with your app, because your app doesn't own this file.

Comment: Exactly ! It's the big problem here...

Comment: @Fuzo Did you find the solution? I have same sitation.